# Create a singleton with unique instance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, singleton

I want to create a store that implements the `Singleton` pattern.

```js
class SingletonStore {
  instance = null;
  constructor(id) {
    console.log(this, 'this obj')
    if (!SingletonStore.instance) {
      this.id = id;
      SingletonStore.instance = this;
    } else {
      return SingletonStore.instance;
    }
  }
}
const emp1 = new SingletonStore(1);
const emp2 = new SingletonStore(2);

console.log("First  : ", emp1);
console.log("Second  : ", emp2);
```

All what i want to achieve is next: when i will call

```
console.log("First  : ", emp1);
console.log("Second  : ", emp2);
```

... in each console.log i want to get only the first instance meaning getting 2 times the store that contains `{id:1}`, but now the second console.log returns the `{id:2}` which is not correct. 
 NOTE: i know that i can achieve this taking outside the singleton the  `instance` parameter. 
Question: How to achive what i described above using my current implementation without creating a variable outside the singleton?

Comment: You'll need a *`static` class property* to store instances on. Currently `instance` is a property of the instance, not the class, so doesn't retain anything across calls.

Comment: @deceze, how to make `instance` as class property in my case?

Comment: `static instance`

Comment: @VLAZ, but if i add `static` keyword in front of `instance` nothing changed. I again get 1 and 2 as ids. Could you help? I am not sure if i understand what @deceze meant.

Comment: You also need to change `this.instance` to `SingletonStore.instance`, otherwise you're still using *the instance* (`this`) to store the attribute.

Comment: @deceze, changed, but nor result there

Comment: You forgot to change one more location…

Comment: @deceze, thanks, it works. But what is the difference between `this. instance ` and `SingletonStore.instance` ?

Comment: `this` refers to *the current instance*, which will always start out blank. Explicitly referring to the class obviously explicitly refers to the class, which can retain values independently of instances.